# PC COM Port Comms to a device with a green light

Tags: serial-port

Ok I need to do something apparantly very simple - send a string of characters to a device at the other end of a com port. 1 cable, 1 weird device, and 1 pc with a com port.

Problem being I am not /that/ old - and a com port to me, looks like what i should be plugging my Atari 2600 joystick into.

I need advice, spcifically 
- best way to send a string of ascii chars out of a COM port?
- how can I tell what if anything is happening?
... if both of these are true... how hard should i kick said device?

Apparently this device will light its green light if i send the right sequence of characters, plz help me make it green.

Comment: What language/platform?  Also, there is nothing inherently "old" about serial ports.  You might be surprised to find what uses them.

Answer (score 0):

In general (and without knowing the platform that you're using) reading and writing to a serial port is almost the same as reading and writing from any other character device, which is almost the same as reading and writing from a file.

It will boil down to 3 operations:

1. Open the serial port, to obtain some kind of file descriptor
2. Configure the speed/handshake/parity/stop-bits of the serial port to match the device you wish to communicate with
3. Read and write from the file descriptor that you obtained in step 1.

If you are running on linux, take a look at the [serial programming howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/) for a reasonably in-depth look at the topic.

For Windows there is the file based approach, as described (amonst other places) [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial_com.aspx). Alternatively, depending on the language you're using, some additional wrappers may have been made available. For example, in VB see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823179).

---

edit: Of course, being able to communicate over the serial port is only the first step. Without some knowledge of the protocol of the device you wish to communicate with you're shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You already know what you have to send. Then simple calculate the checksum of sending byte and send it with your data.

At the receiving end if u got the same databyte along with the checksum then everything will be alright.

Do one more thing while calculating checksum at receiving end place a circle on the form and compare both of checksum (sending databyte and receiving databyte). If they are same then `circle.fillcolor = true`.

In this way you can check everything.